# Trigger display of component with vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have the following code in an html file:

```
<script>
    Vue.component('edit-user', {
        methods: {
            trigger () {
                Event.$emit('editUser');
            }
        },
        template: '<a @click="trigger">Edit</a>'
    });

    new Vue({
        el: '#views',
    });
</script>
```

Then in the relevant place I am calling:

`<edit-user></edit-user>`

The view has root element as `<div id="views">` which encapsulates the whole page. Then I have my editUser.vue component registered. It should just trigger the display of a modal.

For some reason this code doesn't work. I receive an error compiling a template, and the component doesn't even show in my Vue devtools tab.

Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong? My Edit link shows but does absolutely nothing.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: The component is `edit-user`, but the tag is `edit-investor`?

Comment: Hey, thanks caught the typo. Still experiencing the same problem though :(

Comment: It should be `this.$emit`, not `Event.$emit`.